# Why does awk on Mac hang when printing these four characters

Tags: macos, awk, xterm

Why does awk hang on Mac OS 10.6.8 with this input? It's not even possible to ctrl-c or ctrl-z it - have to kill the X-window that xterm is running in.

```
bash-3.2$ awk -version
awk version 20070501

bash-3.2$ echo -en '\xe2\x80\x9d\x0a' | awk '{print}'
â
...awk hangs
```

EDIT: Only seems to hang when run from xterm in X11, works fine for me too in "Terminal" application.

Comment: On my mac, this prints a single double quote character (") and then returns.

Comment: Odd, it works fine on my Mac with bash 3.2.51, and awk 20070501 under Mavericks.

Comment: For me its working too… Just outputs `â` and quits with exit status 0… (OSX 10.9.4, awk 20070501)

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I got a hunch and tried it in the "Terminal" application instead of xterm/X11 and then it worked for me as well. Updated my question to reflect this fact.

Comment: What is the locale setting in the `xterm` vs Terminal?  I have (in Mavericks 10.9.4 — why are you still using 10.6.8?) en_US.UTF-8 (for `$LANG`, that is).  I get to see U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (”).  I guess the other question is "Why `xterm`?"

Comment: Has nothing to do with X11 programming, rather with how xterm is set up on Mac OS X. Removing the x11 tag.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `| awk '{print'}` by `| cat`?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yeah, I got the same result with cat. I guess that means there is some problem with the terminal then.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. In xterm LANG is not set, in Terminal LANG is set to sv_SE.UTF-8 (I'm in Sweden). I use 10.6.8 because I have an old MacBook (2008) which refuses to accept *any* software updates. I use xterm out of habit I guess, since I have used it "all my life" on other Unix machines.

Comment: On my Mac, I have `awk --version` printing `awk version 20070501`. My guess is you have the same.  Have you checked the language settings on your `xterm`; is it also `sv_SE.UTF-8`?  In Terminal, you can check preferences with command-comma and the 'encodings' tab.  I'm not sure about `xterm`; in a VM running Ubuntu 14.04, the terminal…oh, it's a Gnome terminal…well, it has a Terminal option and a Set Character Encoding item under that; maybe `xterm` is faintly similar and has some settings somewhere. I've not yet hit the 'end of upgrades' on my laptops, but they're 2011 and 2009 versions.